# Updating Choice Person/Group columns using listData.svc in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, jquery, people-picker, listdata.svc, choice-field

I am trying to use JQuery and the listData.svc to update a list that has a choice column.

I am using Postman to generate my http requests, can someone please show me examples of how to update choice columns person group columns using listData.svc.

My list is a simple list. Has three columns two have string values the one is a choice between two values Offsite or Onsite. I want to change a column with the value of Offsite to Onsite. I would also like to see an example of how to add/update a value to a person/group column using listData.svc. I have been searching the web but have had much difficulty finding any solid examples for these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with User fields via REST API in SharePoint 2010 (listData.svc) you need to specify `UserId` in `Update` operation.

For example, in Tasks list the column `AssignedTo` in REST would be referenced as `AssignedToId`

### How to update list item using REST API in SharePoint 2010

```
function updateListItem(webUrl,listName,itemId,itemProperties,success, failure)
{
   getListItemById(webUrl,listName,itemId,function(item){

      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: item.__metadata.uri,
         contentType: 'application/json',
         processData: false,
         headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": item.__metadata.etag
         },
         data: Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(itemProperties),
         success: function (data) {
                success(data);
         },
         error: function (data) {
                failure(data);
         }
      });

   },
   function(error){
       failure(error);
   });


}



function getListItemById(webUrl,listName, itemId, success, failure) {
    var url = webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName + "(" + itemId + ")";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data.responseJSON.error);
        }
    });
}
```

### Example

How to set `AssignedTo` field via REST API in SharePoint 2010

```
var taskProperties = {
    'TaskName': 'Approval',
    'AssignedToId': 12
};

updateListItem('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/project/','Tasks',2,taskProperties,function(item){
    console.log('Task has been updated'); 
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

### References

[Using the REST Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)

Comment: I'm glad it helped ;)

Comment: Im receiving this error: Error processing request stream. The property name 'TaskName' specified for type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.TasksItem' is not valid. Any thoughts?